# Toolbar Hidden in a Virtual Page

Tags: php, plugin-development, theme-development, wp-query, pages

I am trying to create a virtual page, but my admin toolbar is not showing up.

This is how I am creating the virtual page:

#### functions.php

```
add_action('init', function()
{
    add_rewrite_rule('register$', 'index.php?virtualpage=1', 'top');
});

add_filter('query_vars', function($query_vars)
{
    $query_vars[] = 'virtualpage';
    return $query_vars;
});

add_action( 'parse_request', function(&$wp)
{
    if (array_key_exists('virtualpage', $wp->query_vars))
    {
        switch ($wp->query_vars['virtualpage'])
        {
            case '1': include 'page-register.php';
        }
        exit();
    }
    return;
});
```

#### page-register.php

```
<?php
add_filter('wp_title', function($title, $sep, $seplocation) { return 'Register'; }, 10, 2);

get_header();
get_template_part('includes/breadcrumbs');
get_template_part('includes/top_info');
?>
<div id="content" class="clearfix fullwidth">
    <div id="left-area">

        <?php
        $form = new Zebra_Form('form');
        $form->add('label', 'label_email', 'email', 'Email');
        $form->add('text', 'email', '', array('autocomplete' => 'off'));
        $form->add('submit', 'btnsubmit', 'Submit');
        $form->render();
        ?>

    </div>
</div> <!-- end #content -->
<?php get_footer();
```

What am I doing wrong?

#### Solution

Based on the response, I attached a function to the 'template_redirect' action instead of the 'parse_request' action as follows:

```
add_action('template_redirect', function()
{
    global $wp;

    if (array_key_exists('virtualpage', $wp->query_vars))
    {
        switch ($wp->query_vars['virtualpage'])
        {
            case '1': include 'page-register.php';
        }
        exit();
    }
    return;
});
```

Comment: Hint: You should `break;` at the end of your `case` in your `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

The admin bar is [initialized on `template_redirect`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6.1/wp-includes/admin-bar.php#L40). You must be short-circuiting that.

The quick and dirty method would be to run `_wp_admin_bar_init();` near the top of your page.

```
add_filter('wp_title', function($title, $sep, $seplocation) { return 'Register'; }, 10, 2);

_wp_admin_bar_init(); // <- this <-

get_header();
get_template_part('includes/breadcrumbs');
get_template_part('includes/top_info');
```

It would be somewhat neater to simply hook your function to `template_redirect` instead, though, and unless you have compelling reasons to be using the somewhat odd hook choice of `parse_query`, that is what I'd recommend.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function()
{
    global $wp_query;
    if (array_key_exists('virtualpage', $wp_query->query_vars))
    {
        switch ($wp_query->query_vars['virtualpage'])
        {
            case '1' :
                include 'page-register.php';
                break;
        }
        exit();
    }
    return;
});
```

Comment: but the template_redirect action does not pass in $wp, right?  So then I would have to use something like is_page($name)?  I tried implementing this before but I was having an issue where any page with the specified variable was loading the registration page (i.e. both www.domain.com/event/register and www.domain.com/register).  Any ideas on how I could just have www.domain.com/register resolve to the page?

Comment: Sorry, that sound like a different question that how to get the admin bar to show up. Plus, that comment is confusing.

Comment: Okay disregard my previous comment. I tried implementing your solution but it threw an error because I do not believe that 'template_redirect' does not pass through any parameters. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I think I figured it out!

Comment: You are right. `template_redirect` does not pass in `wp_query` but `$wp_query` is a global. The fix is pretty simple.